# Running PowerShell in C# with PSCommand.AddCommand() instead of PSCommand.AddScript()

Tags: c#, powershell

We're updating our Exchange server and have been instructed to change our existing code so it no longer calls *PSCommand.AddScript();* but should instead use the *PSCommand.AddCommand();* method. With *PSCommand.AddScript();*, it was easy enough to throw an entire script at it, like:

```
PSCommand script = new PSCommand();

script.AddScript(String.Format("Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn\r\n\r\n(get-mailuser | select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses).proxyaddressstring", settings.ExchangeServerUri));
```

But with *PSCommand.AddCommand();*, each command, argument, and parameter must be added individually. What I've come up with:

```
PSCommand script = new PSCommand();

script.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin").AddArgument("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn");

script.AddCommand("get-mailuser").AddCommand("select").AddParameter("ExpandProperty")

                    .AddArgument("emailaddresses").AddParameter("property", "proxyadressstring");
```

Invoking gives me this error:

> {"The term 'get-mailuser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."}

I'm guessing I'm not adding things in the right order, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you need to call `AddStatement()` before the next `AddCommand()`. Take a moment to have a look at the documentation or read some examples.